# Listen to what files are being read/written to from a Node.js spawned process

Tags: node.js, io, filesystems, listener, std

I'd like to stream the file paths that are being read and written to from a spawned child process in Node, for some reason I can't figure out how to do this and I can't find any similar questions (would've thought this would've been more widely needed).

My current code is this

```
    let Client = spawn('Program.exe', []);
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: Client.stdin
    });
    rl.on("line", line => {
        logger.info(line);
    });
```

However, this only logs the output of the program, not what it's reading/writing to/from.

Comment: There's nothing built-into node.js that lets you monitor what files some other process is reading from and writing to.  You'd have to look in your OS and see if such a capability exists and if anyone has provided a module for node.js that lets you use it from node.js (or build your own nodejs add-on that uses it).

Comment: FYI, if you explain what the actual problem is that you're trying to solve (what you've described so far is one possible technique for solving your problem - their may be others), then we might be able to help in other ways.

Comment: Basically I'm creating a private server for a game, so I need to know where the game is storing the logged in user data, I couldn't find it in any obvious place (game files, appdata, etc) so my next best option was to listen to what files it's reading at the start of the game.

Comment: So, you're trying to reverse engineer where the game is storing things?  You probably need an OS tool, not something in node.js.  You don't say what OS you're on, but on Windows, you can start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) with Process Monitor.

Comment: I am on Windows, already tried process monitor, that's the first thing I did. Only problem is, when I start the game, it instantly fills up with 17,000+ entries to random DLLs and lib files like razer synapse. Very very hard to sift through and find where it's actually getting the user info from, Edit: I already have it filtered to only be things from the game

Comment: Save the content to a text file and process it with searching or a script to sift through it to find what you want.   If it's a busy program that accesses tons of resources, you're just going to have to do some manual or coding work to sift through it all and find what you want.  There isn't likely a shortcut.  You should be able to end with a list of files that it accesses that you can page through to find what you want.